# Taking Square Root of Pythagorean Theorem

Tags: geometry

If one can take of the square roots of both sides of $x^2 = 4^2$ and correctly say that $x = 4$, like here:

$$\begin{align*} x^2 &= 4^2 \\
\sqrt{x^2} &= \sqrt{4^2} \\
x &= 4 \end{align*}$$

Why can't one solve the Pythagorean Theorem the same way? It doesn't work, as pictured below:
$$\begin{align*} 3^2+4^2 &= x^2 \\
\sqrt{3^2+4^2} &= \sqrt{x^2} \\
3+4 &= x \\
7 &= x \end{align*}$$

$x$ actually equals $5$.

$$\begin{align*} 3^2+4^2 &= 5^2\\
9+16 &= 25 \end{align*}$$

Ever since I was 10, I was taught that one could do whatever he wanted to one side of an algebraic inequality so long as he did the same thing to the other side. This isn't in violation of that rule.

So why doesn't it work?

Comment: It doesn't work because $(a + b)^2 \ne a^2 + b^2$ so $\sqrt{(a + b)^2} \ne \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.

Comment: What you *can* do that *will* be correct (but won't help you)is $3^2 + 4^2 = x^2 \implies 3^2 + 2*3*4 + 4^2 = x^2 + 2*3*4 \implies \sqrt {(3 + 4)^2} = \sqrt{x^2 + 14}\implies 7 = \sqrt{x^2 + 14}$.  That is absolutely 100% true and accurate.  It's also completely useless but ... you *can* take square roots of both sides.  It's just $\sqrt{3^2 + 4^2} \ne 3 + 4$.

Comment: Yep. You can transform one side of an algebraic *equality* (not inequality) as long as you do the exact same to the other side. So you're right when you go from $3^2+4^2=x^2$ to $\sqrt{3^2+4^2}=\sqrt{x^2}$. You simply took the square root of both sides. In the next step however, you tried simplifying both sides but got the left-hand side wrong. While it's true that $\sqrt{x^2}$ reduces to $x$, it's *very false* that $\sqrt{3^2+4^2}$ becomes $3+4$.

Comment: Arrgh.  In my comment $2*3*4 = 24 \ne 14$!!! Oh, well.  ... mistakes happen.  (Note that $7 = \sqrt{x^2 + 24} = \sqrt{25 + 24} = \sqrt{49}$.  So... yep, square roots of both sides work.

Answer (score 2):

In general, $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \neq a + b$. Indeed, if we square both expressions, we get $$a^2 + b^2 \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad (a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2 a b + b^2,$$ and we immediately see that these are unequal unless $a = 0$ or $b = 0$. In particular, this is not a matter of applying a given operation to both sides, it's a problem with simplification.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot claim that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=a+b.$ As noted above, $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ by the binomial theorem.

For your first example, it is correct to say that $\sqrt{x^2}=x.$ Technically, there is a negative solution also, but since we are talking about the lengths of a triangle, we only need to consider the positive solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your calculation you want
$$
3^2 + 4^2 = (3 + 4)^2
$$
which in general is not the case.

The square root will operate on the result of $3^2 + 4^2$, not on the individual terms $3^2$ and $4^2$.